# Generated Shim does not contain generic overloads of a method (that their types are constrained to be struct)

Tags: c#, generics, microsoft-fakes, shim

I am using Microsoft fakes to test our code base which is using a third party assembly.
Our code is calling a static generic method of a class that has several non-generic overloads.
Something like this :

```
ILookupResult Serivce.Lookup<T>(int code);
ILookupResult Service.Lookup(Type type,int code);
```

The problem is that the generated shim has an entry for each non-generic method like this :

```
ShimService.LookupTypeInt32
```

but there's no enrty for generic methods and I don't have any clue why it's like this.

**UPDATE 1:** it may worth mentioning that:

- Generating stubs for this third party assembly is not possible I have
  disabled stub generation.
- Other generic methods are generated.

**UPDATE 2**: Okay now I know what is the problem by setting Diagnostic attribute of Fake node into true.It said "unsupported constraint type" which made me take a better look at the interface and I noticed that T should be struct:

```
 ILookupResult Serivce.Lookup<T>(int code) where T:struct;
```

now the question is why struct is unsupported in shim generation ?

Comment: That is odd. When I do a simple test with the same names I get a shim method named `LookupOf1Int32`. What versions of VisualStudio and Microsoft.QualityTools.Test.Fakes.dll are you using?

Comment: @JackA. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and version 12.0.0.0 of Microsoft.QualityTools.Test.Fakes.dll

Comment: OK, I was using VS2013 but the same fakes version. Have you tested to see if the `LookupTypeInt32` shim that it creates is the one that gets called when your `Lookup<T>(int)` method is called?

Comment: @JackA. yes I have tested it and it doesn't refer to generic one thus I am getting an error when code reaches this method call.

Comment: You mention that you've disabled stubs generation. Did you do that by modifying the .fakes file? Is it possible that you also disabled shims generation? You may want to try removing the fakes DLL and the .fakes file, then re-adding them. If you do that, be sure to watch for errors during the process.

Comment: @JackA : I have updated the question. I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Interesting. I haven't run into that one before, but I see the same thing when I add the constraint to my test. I even see the "unstubbable" error when I disable stub generation. It appears to be a limitation of MS Fakes but I have no idea why.

Comment: A couple other thoughts. First, that seems like an odd method signature. Do you know the reason that the method is generic? Does it affect the output in some way (because it doesn't affect the input)? Second, I typically try to write a simple abstraction layer over any third party components I use. This can be used to isolate my core code from its peculiarities and allows me to swap out the component later. This approach may be helpful for you here. Finally, if you have any MS Support tickets available, it may be worth using one of them to see if they have any workarounds.

Comment: @JackA : The problem is this code is part of our framework (not a third party component)that our developers use (thus I do not have any control on how the code is written).If that's a limitation of Fakes I am afraid we can't test our codes. :(